# Swift Compiler Error Class Variable not yet supported in Xcode 6.2? How to I fix this

Tags: ios, swift, xcode-6.2

This is the code in my commonutils.swift folder.   I am getting an error stating class variable not yet supported.  Can someone help me to understand what to do so that I can fix this?  Please

```
class CommonUtils: NSObject {
  class let cache = NSCache()

  class func clearCache() {
    cache.removeAllObjects()
  }

  class func cacheObject(object: AnyObject, key: String) {
    cache.setObject(object, forKey: key)
  }

  class func cachedObject(key: String) -> AnyObject? {
    return cache.objectForKey(key)
  }

  class func showAlert(title : String, message : String, delegate : NSObject) {
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: delegate, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
  }

  class func showAlert(title : String, message : String, delegate : NSObject, button : String) {
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: title, message: message, delegate: delegate, cancelButtonTitle: button)
    alert.show()
  }

  class func getTextHeight(text: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let nsString = NSString(string: text)
    let attributeDict : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: font, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
  }

  class func getWidthOfString(text: String, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let attributeDict : NSDictionary = NSDictionary(object: font, forKey: NSFontAttributeName)
    let attributedString : NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributeDict as [NSObject : AnyObject])
    return attributedString.size().width
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `static` instead of `class` on the `cache` variable

Comment: I tried static and it didnt work

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: static properties are only allowed between structs and enums

Comment: Ah ok, it works in Swift 2 - any reason why you are still using Xcode 6.2

Comment: If I use xcode 6.3 will it automatically fix.  Will there be any compilation errors

Comment: You are using < Swift 1.2 , which is now really out of date - the current version is Swift 2.1. I'd advise you to upgrade to the latest Xcode (7.2). It won't just work - a lot has changed since Swift 1 and you'll probably have to make a lot of boring minor fixes to make things compile, which will be a pain. On the other hand, if you keep going with Swift 1 you'll keep running into these kinds of issues. Up to you really - I guess it depends on your project and what you want to do with it.

Comment: I tried to install 7.2 and it doesnt work with this  OS.  Any suggestions?

Comment: From looking around it seems that `static` on class variables was introduced in Swift 1.2 (so Xcode 6.3). So you could try that, if you aren't able to upgrade your OS.